Physical Interpretation of BEC Formation
I have recently worked through a theoretical argument for why Bose-Einstein Condensation occurs. If we are comparing an ensemble of distinguishable versus indistinguishable particles, we can compute the statistics for the probability of finding atoms in the ground state. If we do so, we see that it is much more likely to find atoms in the ground state in the case of indistinguishable atoms. This seems to be due to the fact that there are many more ways of finding the particle elsewhere in the case of distinguishable atoms.
I am reading "Quantum Atom Optics" by Byrnes, and it is said in section 2.2 that

we can imagine there is a gas of bosonic atoms and the system is
cooled down enough such that the spatial degrees of freedom are all
the same for all particles.

In this case, it would seem that this cooling process is what allows the BEC to form as a result of the particles losing their spatial separability and becoming indistinguishable.
I am wondering what the physical mechanism for the process of BEC formation is? I understand the statistical argument but am looking for conceptual backing to expand on this mathematical understanding. If I look at this situation from the particle's point of view, I am not seeing what is physically different that allows for the formation of a BEC. How does the lack of spatial separability influence the particles and give rise to this behavior?

What I get from Einsteins Original work (https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_ap/demokritov/mbecfornonphysicists/einstein_1924_1925.pdf) is that he found, that the numbers of atom n that can be distributed at the energy levels is limited (equation 24) for a certain temperature and a certain volume V.
$$n = (2\pi m k_B T)^{3/2} / h^3 \sum \tau^{3/2} $$
The sum just gives a constant factor.
Imagine that every energy state is occupied -- the gas is saturated. Now you increase the pressure (e.g. reduce the volume). What can happen? Einstein found that the only that can be occupied is the ground state. Increasing the pressure will result in an accumulation of atoms in the ground state.
Nowadays, not the pressure is increased, but the temperature is lowered to form a Bose-Einstein condensate.
